# Passing data to a function as a key and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to execute a function as follows, but am not succeeding.

```
var leagueSelect = "allLeagues";

loadTable("#loadLeaguesTable","php/leagueTable.php",'leagueSelect',leagueSelect);
```

The `loadTable` function:

```
function loadTable(tableDiv, tableURL, tableType, tableVal){
    $.post(tableURL,{tableType:tableVal},function(data){
        $(tableDiv).append(data);
    });
}
```

I'm trying to send the values in the post in this format: `{ leagueSelect: leagueSelect }`.

If I hard-code `leagueSelect` into my function in place of the tableType parameter in the $.post function, it works.

How am I supposed to send 'leagueSelect' properly in my function call?

I'm thinking the `data[key] = value` method but I didn't get that working either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign the variable you're actually creating a new object with the property `tableType` set to whatever the tableVal value is.

Instead you need to use the `object[key] = val;` syntax or pass the post data in directly like this:

```
var leagueSelect = "allLeagues";

loadTable("#loadLeaguesTable", "php/leagueTable.php", { leagueSelect: leagueSelect });

function loadTable(tableDiv, tableURL, postData) {
    $.post(tableURL, postData, function(data) {
        $(tableDiv).append(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: @user3697407 Great!  I just edited it with a simpler slightly different method.  If I answered your question please hit the checkmark at the top left of this answer. Thank you!